# Twitter Json data not getting queried in Hive

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive

I trying to do twitter sentiment analysis using Flume, Hadoop and Hive. 
 I am following this [article](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/analyse-tweets-using-flume-hadoop-and.html#comment-form_2593107193473097670) . I was able to get tweets to HDFS successfully by using Flume. This is my Twitter-agent configuration.

```html
#setting properties of agent
Twitter-agent.sources=source1
Twitter-agent.channels=channel1
Twitter-agent.sinks=sink1

#configuring sources
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.type=com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.channels=channel1
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.consumerKey=<consumer-key>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.consumerSecret=<consumer-secret>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.accessToken=<access-token>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.accessTokenSecret=<Access-Token-secret>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.keywords= morning, night, hadoop, bigdata

#configuring channels
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.type=memory
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.capacity=10000
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity=100

#configuring sinks
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.channel=channel1
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.type=hdfs
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path=flume/tweets
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.rollSize=0
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.rollCount=10000
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.batchSize=1000
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.fileType=DataStream
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.writeFormat=Text
```

Then I created a table just like in the article and the table was created. When I query the table,it gives error like this

```css
hive> select * from tweets;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('S' (code 83)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@31228d83; line: 1, column: 2]
Time taken: 0.914 seconds
```

I tried other queries like `select count(id) from tweets` but it shows a lot of errors.

This is the one of FlumeData file(tweets) present in HDFS.

```css
SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;�@z_�>��<���N ����{"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"613363183034601472","in_reply_to_status_id":613363183034601472,"created_at":"Tue Jun 23 15:09:32 +0000 2015","in_reply_to_user_id_str":"604605328","source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>","retweet_count":0,"retweeted":false,"geo":null,"filter_level":"low","in_reply_to_screen_name":"AlexiBlue","id_str":"613363262760034304","in_reply_to_user_id":604605328,"favorite_count":0,"id":613363262760034304,"text":"@AlexiBlue good morning ☺️","place":null,"lang":"en","favorited":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"coordinates":null,"truncated":false,"timestamp_ms":"1435072172237","entities":{"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[{"indices":[0,10],"screen_name":"AlexiBlue","id_str":"604605328","name":"Alexi Blue ★","id":604605328}],"trends":[],"symbols":[]},"contributors":null,"user":{"utc_offset":null,"friends_count":1175,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604664190763212800/Nmqxn_p5_normal.jpg","listed_count":6,"profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","default_profile_image":false,"favourites_count":31695,"description":"PIZZA & TACOS ARE LIFE. #flippinfamily #rudunation #ABNation #5quad #7squad #SamCollinsisbaeaf","created_at":"Sun Mar 09 02:40:15 +0000 2014","is_translator":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","protected":false,"screen_name":"Sonja_Campbell1","id_str":"2379671544","profile_link_color":"3B94D9","id":2379671544,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","lang":"en","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_text_color":"333333","verified":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604664190763212800/Nmqxn_p5_normal.jpg","time_zone":null,"url":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2379671544/1434956813","statuses_count":17254,"follow_request_sent":null,"followers_count":871,"profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"following":null,"name":"Sonita✨","location":"","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","notifications":null}}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: try with Text format first (check), later with squence , by setting TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

Comment: I gave it as Text Format

Comment: ! but the file is getting stored as Sequence format ?? as seen in your question

Comment: I have included the content of Twitter-agent.conf file in the question. Please do have a look.

Answer (score 0):

SerDe is short for Serializer/Deserializer. Hive uses the SerDe interface for IO. And json is one format supported among many. I can see the serde exception and json in your error message. So its something to do with marshalling and unmarshalling of json data present in hive table column. Identify into which column are you adding json data. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Download "hive-json-serde.jar" and Add it to hive shell before you query any table which contains SerDe data such json, etc.

You will have to do this everytime you open Hive shell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and add hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in your hive shell which has the JSON serde by clodera. Then you need to create a table based on your required columns.

For example

```
create external table load_tweets(id BIGINT,text STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets'
```

To perform sentiment analysis tweet_id and the tweeted_text are enough. Now if you use

```
select * from load_tweets;
```

Then you can see the data in your hive table containing tweet_id and the tweet_text.

You can refer to the below link in which sentiment analysis has been clearly explained with screen shots.

https://acadgild.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-on-tweets-with-apache-hive-using-afinn-dictionary/